# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1]

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.uiyoutube">
    <uses-sdk
        tools:overrideLibrary="com.uiyoutube, com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer" />
    <application android:allowBackup="false" tools:replace="android:allowBackup"/>
</manifest>
```

I tried implements `LifecycleOwner`.

So I imported:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
```

I had to:

```
@Override
 public Lifecycle getLifecycle () {
     return null;
 }
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>
> Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1.
>
> Required by:
>
> ProvaMaterialModule:app:unspecified > ProvaMaterialModule:react-native-material-letter-icon:unspecified

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"

    compile  'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1'
    compile  'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

I tried to replace `compile` with 
`implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"`

but I get the following error:

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependenc
yHandler.
```

Some advice?

Comment: Replace `compile` with `implementation`.

Comment: @MohammadAli: As I wrote I tried it, it gives me the following error: Could not find method implementation () for arguments [android.arch.lifecycle: extensions: 1.1.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl .dependencies.DefaultDependenc
yHandler.

Comment: please try to create a new Android Project and compare your gradle with new gradle. you can understand your self.

Comment: Forgive me I'm not understanding. What I'm creating is a bridge for native react by installing the module: com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer: core: 8.0.1
But I need LifecycleOwner, but I need to import its library.

So could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components

To add it to your project, open the `build.gradle` file for your project (not the ones for your app or module) and add the `google()` repository as shown below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried, it gives me the following error:> Could not find method google () for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: update your gradle inside `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: Use version: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: your `classpath` is also up-to-date? `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`

Comment: I've also tried: distributionUrl = https \: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-rc-1-all.zip

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha03'
}

Could not find method google () for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: You also tried this? https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/584

Comment: I looked at the link you posted, but I did not find a solution.